# Connecting from Node backend to Fabric results in Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

When I try to connect to a fabric i get the error:

> Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames: "$IPNAMEHERE is not in the cert's list:"

And I cant seem to figure it out. I tried changing the name of the ca on init like so:

`fabric-ca-init -b BOOTSTRAP USERPASS --csr.cn IPNAME`

and yet that error persists. Is there a way to add a hostname/IP to the certificate?

Comment: Which type of node (fabric-ca, peer, orderer) are you trying to connect to?

Comment: I am attempting to connect to a peer node

Comment: Are you using one of the sample networks?  Are you using cryptogen to create the key material?

Comment: No I am generating the certificates with the fabric-ca.
You can replicate this issue by using the fabric-ca network, and changing the common name to a different hostname than localhost. the fabric-ca user guide says that you need to do that to tls in from a different location

Comment: Are you running `fabric-ca-client enroll ...` ?  If so, then you should be able to pass in `--csr.hosts IPNAME`

Comment: I passed that in and i ended up with a response of "Bad certificate" i tried changing the --csr.hosts to the ipnames and that did not solve the issue either

Comment: I assume that was a different error?  How are you connecting?  peer cli?  You'll also need to set the trusted root(s) as well

Comment: My original error was the Hostname/IP doesn't match after attempting to sign in from the Node SDK. this would occur if i try to connect and set the verify option in the TLS options to true. if i set it to false then i get an error from the CA saying bad certificate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original issue was the

> Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames: "$IPNUMBERHERE is not in the cert's list:"

To resolve it I added the $IPNUMBER to the certificate authorities csr.hosts, that was still triggering the issue because when i was connecting via the node sdk i did not turn off verify and so i believe it was attempting to match the certificate against the IPNUMBER not the certificate authority that lived in that VM. 
I also enrolled the administrative users with the csr.hosts IPNUMBER.